# jQuery result in text field

Tags: jquery, html, function, textfield

How to put jquery result in text field. Here is the code:
 jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('p, li, a, href').click(function () {
            var xpath = getXPath(this);
            alert(xpath);
        });
    });
```

and HTML text field:

```
<input name="" type="text" value="">
```

What I need is instead alert put result in text field?

UPDATE:

Sorry for my bad question...

The result must be in selected text field:

```
<input id="" name="" type="text" value="">
<input id="" name="" type="text" value="">
<input id="" name="" type="text" value="">
```

and must write result in selected text field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to select the focused element

```
$(':focus').val(xpath);
```

this one is even much better that you give them all a name for example:

```
<input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
<input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
<input id="" name="myinput" type="text" value="">
```

then select them like this:

```
$('input[name="myinput"]').is(":focus").val(xpath);
```

if your textbox loose focus when you try to trigger script do this:

```
var selectedtextbox;
$('input[name="myinput"]').focus(function(){selectedtextbox=$(this);});
```

then in your sctipt use:

```
selectedtextbox.val(xpath);
```

make sure that selectedtextbox is global and can be accessed from your script.

Comment: did you check my last answer? this will surely do what you want. of course if not your script is triggered by a click that will cause textbox to loose focus

Comment: i'm updated the code but probbaly lose focus. How to solve this http://jsfiddle.net/YrTHZ/1/

Comment: i updated the answer again, for the case focus is lost. try this ;)

Comment: Can you please add this code to: http://jsfiddle.net/YrTHZ/2/ becouse I'm not sure where to add selecredtextbox.val(xpath);

Comment: just give me a mitute, i'll try to fix it

Comment: i solved the problem, the problem was that you have given the textboxes id="myinput" instead of the name="myinput" code was correct. now its working:

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('p, li, a, href').click(function () {
            var xpath = getXPath(this);
            $('#inputId').val(xpath)
        });
    });


<input id="inputId" name="" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xpath = getXPath(this);
$("#yourInputId").val(xpath);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Give that field an `id` attribute
   `<input name="" type="text" value="" id="thatfield">`
2. Put the value to the field
   `$("#thatfield").val(xpath)`

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p, li, a, href').click(function () {
        var xpath = getXPath(this);
        $("#thatfield").val(xpath);
    });
});
```

documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: I UPDATE the question:

Sorry for my bad question:(

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than 1 input at your page you must give an 'id' to your input

```
 <input name="" type="text" id="myinput" value="">
```

Then you can select your input with `$('#myinput')`

This version below shows the situation of only one input in page.
If there is more than 1 input in your page you must change you input like above and change `$('input')` to `$('#myinput')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('p, li, a, href').click(function () {
            var xpath = getXPath(this);
            $('input').val(xpath);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I UPDATE the question:

Sorry for my bad question:(

Comment: No, I want to write jquery result in field who in focus

Comment: and how to select input with $('#myinput') where i need to add this to the code

Comment: $('input').val(xpath);  -->   $('#myinput').val(xpath);

Comment: I'm tryied this but write result only in one text filed (in first)

Comment: Then you will need to use class like this:http://jsfiddle.net/YrTHZ/3/ jQuery selects only one element for prompt id.

Comment: but now select all elements (all 3 element text fields get the same text) :)

Comment: NO, i want to first when i click on text write result in first field, then when i click second time on text then write result on second text field but first stay the same, then click third time on tect and get result in third text field... or if is posible to get result in focused text-field

Comment: :) You make me exhausted :) Wait a bit

Comment: BINGO, but when i erase the text from field then can't write again, but THANKS A LOT

Comment: No problem. http://jsfiddle.net/YrTHZ/11/ try this. When you delete it you can select again.

Answer (score 0):

well simply you can give your input a id:

```
<input name="" type="text" id="myinput" value="">
```

and then set its value attribute:

```
$(#myinput").val(xpath);
```

Comment: I UPDATE the question:

Sorry for my bad question:(

Comment: but how do you select the textbox? do they have checkboxes?

Comment: No, I want to write jquery result in field who in focus

Comment: what triggers the script? because if you click on anything the focus will leave the textbox

Comment: I have an script who get xpath. Now i want to write result in field who is in focus. Example. first I click on text field to select in which text field write result then click on html code to get xpath and write in selected field if this possible?

Comment: i added the code in your given address, but i don't know how to test it and what to do, can you please test it and tell me if it works?